# How to compare DateTime or MutableDateTime objects correctly in Joda Time?

Tags: java, jodatime

The output of my code is 0,0,0. I was expecting 0, -1 , 1 instead. What is the problem in the code ? Why can't I add or subtract seconds from a DateTime?

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();    
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(dt1); // dt2 = dt1
    DateTime dt3 = new DateTime(dt1); // dt3 < dt1
    DateTime dt4 = new DateTime(dt1); // dt4 > dt1

    dt3.minusSeconds(10);
    dt4.plusSeconds(10);

    int result1 = dt1.compareTo(dt2);
    int result2 = dt1.compareTo(dt3);
    int result3 = dt1.compareTo(dt4);

    System.out.println("Results " + result1 + " , " + result2 + " , " + result3);

}
```

Comment: attempting same code with MutableDateTime. API says DateTime is immutable. API - DateTime is thread-safe and immutable, provided that the Chronology is as well. All standard Chronology classes supplied are thread-safe and immutable.  also read- http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusDays%28int%29

Comment: With MutableDateTime you'd want to use add, not plus.

Comment: @JonSkeet - yes. But, I don't see a minusSeconds() like method in MutableDateTime. Why is this so ? How will I do minus now ?

Comment: Just call `addSeconds(-10)`. Or ideally, avoid MutableDateTime entirely...

Comment: @JonSkeet - oh yes ! basic math. But, this gives negative time. Please see my answer for details.

Comment: @JonSkeet - added my response. please review.

Comment: "avoid MutableDateTime entirely" is not allways a good idea. For example, in case of performance is important. In real time application, i use exclusively MutableDateTime instances to appy computations on date. Otherwise, lags happen.
In batch applications, i do the same thing.
We must not generalise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`minusSeconds()`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html#minusSeconds%28int%29) returns a copy of your DateTime object.

You could try this:

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();    
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(dt1); // dt2 = dt1
    DateTime dt3 = new DateTime(dt1).minusSeconds(10); // dt3 < dt1
    DateTime dt4 = new DateTime(dt1).plusSeconds(10); // dt4 > dt1

    int result1 = dt1.compareTo(dt2);
    int result2 = dt1.compareTo(dt3);
    int result3 = dt1.compareTo(dt4);

    System.out.println("Results " + result1 + " , " + result2 + " , " + result3);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

`minusSeconds` and `plusSeconds` returns a copy of the [DateTime](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html).

You need to re-assign your variables:

```
dt3 = dt3.minusSeconds(10);
dt4 = dt4.plusSeconds(10);
```

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime` is **immutable**. When you do `dt3.minusSeconds(10);`, then the `DateTime` object that `dt3` refers to is not modified; instead, it returns a new `DateTime` object. Change your code to this:

```
dt3 = dt3.minusSeconds(10);
dt4 = dt4.plusSeconds(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Edited the code in my question to take years into account instead of seconds (see below). This easily lets us see if we get -ve time when we do addYears( - Some big int ). We get a negative value which is okay mathematically, but is not used in real life.

```
public static void main(String[]args){

    DateTime dt1 = new DateTime();    
    DateTime dt2 = new DateTime(dt1); // dt2 = dt1
    DateTime dt3 = new DateTime(dt1); // dt3 < dt1
    DateTime dt4 = new DateTime(dt1); // dt4 > dt1
    MutableDateTime mdt1 = new MutableDateTime(dt1); // mdt1 = dt1
    mdt1.addYears(-10);

    dt3 = dt3.minusYears(10);
    dt4 = dt4.plusYears(10);

    int result1 = dt1.compareTo(dt2);
    int result2 = dt1.compareTo(dt3);
    int result3 = dt1.compareTo(dt4);

    System.out.println("Results " + result1 + " , " + result2 + " , " + result3);
    System.out.println("IMmutable is " + dt1);
    System.out.println("mutable is " + mdt1);

    mdt1.addYears(-10000);
    System.out.println("mutable is " + mdt1);


}
```

Comment: It's not at all clear why you've added this as an *answer*, and you haven't specified any output either. As for whether negative values are used in real life - they absolutely are. 10000 years ago is ~8000 BC... What's your point here?

Comment: Sorry. Output is as expected in the question. My mistake. I rarely come across negative times (eg. 10 hours ago) in real life and assumed that they won't be needed.

Comment: No, they're pretty common. For example, "I expect this authentication token to have been generated at most 10 minutes ago" or "I expect the user to be at least 18 years old, i.e. birthdate is less than "now - 18 years"